# LikeView In Android Not Working

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout

`Hello, 
i am developing an android application using the facebook SDK for android.

i have a LikeView as below

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/likeview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

The Code ib

```
 LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeview);
                likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                        "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
                        LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

its not working, no window or application opens

can anybody help?

Comment: Have you looked in logcat to see if there are any errors? Do you have the Facebook app installed? What version of Android is your device on?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Answering the three questions asked by Ming Li will help us to help you...

Answer (score 1):

1) Initialize the Facebook SDK
2) Find your `LikeView` 
3) Set your facebook page and type using `setObjectIdAndType`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType( "https://www.facebook.com/you_page",
 LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

4) Update your manifest file as: 
    4.1) Add meta with facebook app id

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

4.2) Add provider

```
 <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderYOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"     
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: in manifest file--
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderYOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

Comment: Could you please make the answer clearer? Comments are not for adding additional info to the answer. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29534326/edit) your original answer to improve it!

Comment: 1)initialize facebook sdk           
2)find your LikeView             
3)set your facebook page and type using setObjectIdAndType            


4)update you manifest file              
4.1)add meta with facebook app id                  
4.2) add privider              
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderYOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_I‌​D" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true"/>

Comment: Again, please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29534326/edit) button!

Comment: Hello..Can we like any post using this like view?